# Firebase download progress bar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to show a download progress bar to show the user how many bytes are left to download before my app continues to the next activity (instead of showing just a black screen). I have attempted it with this code:

```
task.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            private float previouslyTransferedBytes = 0;
            private boolean firstProgress = true;
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
            public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //update total bytes to download
                if(firstProgress){
                    Intent totalBytesToDownloadIntent = new Intent(Code.TOTAL_BYTES_TO_TRANSFER);
                    float totalbytecount = taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    totalBytesToDownloadIntent.putExtra(Code.TOTAL_BYTES_TO_TRANSFER,totalbytecount);
                    GlobalVars.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(totalBytesToDownloadIntent);
                    firstProgress = false;
                }
                float newlyTransfered = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()-previouslyTransferedBytes;
                Intent downloadProgress = new Intent(Code.DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
                downloadProgress.putExtra(Code.BYTES_TRANSFERED,newlyTransfered);
                GlobalVars.applicationContext.sendBroadcast(downloadProgress);
                previouslyTransferedBytes = taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
            }

        });
```

but total bytecount only returns -1. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: the file definitely exists as it gets correctly downloaded and used later on in the app.

EDIT 2: "task" is of type FileDownloadTask.

Comment: Which `getXXX()` method (`getFile()`, `getBytes()`, `getStream()`) are you using to do the download?

Comment: i am using getFile()

Comment: You are using string `Code.TOTAL_BYTES_TO_TRANSFER` both as an intent action and as the key to store extra `totalbytecount`.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes. I have also already checked that my broadcast listener in the activity receives the intents (making sure that broadcast listener is registered and that it has the correct filter).

Comment: Where are you observing the bad value of `totalByteCount`?  After it's been stored as an extra and received by your broadcast listener?  As a further check, add a `Log` statement or `System.out.println()` to output it in your progress listener.

Comment: I am observing it when stepping through the onProgress listener in debug and then adding the log statement to the onProgress method and in the intent listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `onProgress()` of a `onProgressListener` for a download is called the first time, `getBytesTransferred() == 0` and `getTotalByteCount() == -1`.  On subsequent calls, the total byte count is correct.  I don't know if this is a bug or simply an undocumented detail of the API.  You could report to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to get their feedback.